# Pass a parameter to Url.Action

Tags: javascript, asp.net, parameters, google-api, infowindow

this is my javascript function:

```
function addMarker(x, y, meas_type, meas_status, meas_key) {
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
            var contentString = '<h3 >' + meas_type + '</h3>' + '<p>Status: ' + '<span style="color: red">' + meas_status + '</span>' + '</p>' + '<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Details" onclick="window.location.href=\'@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { param = meas_key})\';" />' + '&nbsp;';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
            });
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
        }
```

Now in the contentString variable, I want to pass to the Index method meas_key as a parameter! How can I do it? It's not working like this.

This one works fine but I need to send meas_key as a parameter:

```
var contentString = '<h3 >' + meas_type + '</h3>' + '<p>Status: ' + '<span style="color: red">' + meas_status + '</span>' + '</p>' + '<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Details" onclick="window.location.href=\'@Url.Action("Index", "Home")\';" />' + '&nbsp;';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here is that `@Url.Action` is done on server side, and of course there is no way to pass a javascript variable there. So you might need to do something like this:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")' + '?param=' + meas_type;
var contentString =
    '<h3 >' + meas_type + '</h3>'
    + '<p>Status: ' + '<span style="color: red">' + meas_status + '</span>' + '</p>'
    + '<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Details" onclick="window.location.href=' + url + '" />'
    + '&nbsp;';
```

And you might want to consider templating of some kind to make this HTML construction a bit more readable.

Comment: I think there is a "+" missing after the url but anyways when I click on the button there are no actions.

Comment: @caj, try to debug url and even the whole `contentString`, or at least outputting it to console or alerting them. Do they look right?

Comment: window.location.href in contentString has this value: /Home/Index?param=9

Comment: I think we only have to surround it with '' I tried this but it didn't work:  var url = "\'@Url.Action("MeasDetails", "Home") + '?param=' + meas_key;\'"

Comment: `var url = "\'@Url.Action("MeasDetails", "Home")" + '?param=' + meas_key + "\'";`

Comment: It worked with this value of url! The problem was with the quotes! Thank you! @Andrei